# FPDF Error - Can't get image to appaear on PDF

Tags: image, fpdf

I have a PDF with fillable forms. I can successfully fill the forms and save the new PDF to my server no problem, but I cannot place an image on the PDF. When I remove the Image(....) line the script works great. When I add it back it I get the error.

I think it's trying to look for the method in the wrong file, originally I only included fpdm..php but I tried adding back fpdf.php and it did not help. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method FPDM::Image() in /home/.../formPDF.php on line 113

Code:

```
require('../forms/pdf/fpdf.php');
require('../forms/pdf/fpdm.php');

$pdf = new FPDM($formPDFLocation);


$pdf->Image('images/sig_37-1405313221.png', 100, 20);
$pdf->Load($fields, false); // second parameter: false if field values are in ISO-8859-1, true if UTF-8
$pdf->Merge();

$filename= "../forms/generated/" . $ffID;
$pdf->Output($filename.'.pdf','I');
```

Answer (score 0):

FPDM is not really related to FPDF but simply a script of a FPDF user. You cannot use FPDF methods on an FPDM instance.

If you search for an all in one solution for such task you may take a look at the [SetaPDF-FormFiller](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/demos/fill-form-field-with-image/) component (not free!).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to save the PDF to my server and then add the image but lost the form contents. Code for anyone that is interested in this half solution:

Code for adding image:

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setSourceFile("16.pdf");
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);

 $pdf->Image('car.jpg',20,100);

$pdf->Output();

?>
```